# constructing nondegenerate polygon from n sides by making cuts

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

We are given the length of n sticks and we need to make a polygon using all the n sticks. If it is impossible to construct a nondegenerate polygon from the given n sticks, we can cut one or more sticks into two parts (length of cut part need not be integer).
How many cuts do we need to make for given n values ?

```
 3(n=3)

 1 2 3
```

We cannot construct a triangle so we try to make a square and we cut stick 3 into two parts of length 1 and 2.
thus answer is 1.
How can we solve this for any n numbers given to us ?

Comment: Can I just chime in to say that this question is related to a currently ongoing coding competition on a website and should be considered cheating?

Comment: similar to https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w22/challenges/polygon-making

Comment: @RajSharma exact question

Comment: you can use this link http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96617/determine-if-you-can-build-a-polygon-from-segments

Comment: I also used it to solve this problem..

Answer (score 6):

You always need at most one cut. The sticks can be used to form a polygon as long as there's no stick that's as long as all the others put together. If originally there is such a stick, just cut it in half.

Comment: i just wrote the answer which i got and it is correct as it passed the system tests of contest .Your solution is not exact or much useful,

Comment: @satya: See my comment under your answer. The answers are the same; yours is just somewhat confusingly expressed.

Comment: See uncreative's answer for a correction for $n\lt3$.

Answer (score 5):

You might need 2 cuts in 2 special cases:

- You have a single stick: you must chop twice to make a triangle
- You have 2 sticks of exactly equal length, in this case it doesn't matter if you cut one of the sticks in exactly 1/2 or make one side longer, you won't be able to construct a polygon without also cutting the other stick.

But for most cases:

- make 1 cut if the longest(sticks) $\ge$ sum(rest of sticks)
- Otherwise, 0 cuts are necessary.

Answer (score -2):

I just got the correct solution in some discussion forum of another platform

For a polygon  to be non degenerate polygon,each side of the polygon must satisfy this condition   sum=a$1$ +a$2$+........+a$n$
and a$i$<1/2(sum) wher  1<=i<=n
.Here a$1$,a$2$..... ,a$n$ are the lengths of sticks given to us and every time the above condition a$i$<1/2(sum) is violated for any i,increase the count by 1.

Comment: That's a rather opaque way of stating the solution. Note that at most one stick can violate the condition, so the count can be at most $1$.